# Loss function Neuronal Network Binary classification averaged labels

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

Background information:
I am trying to build a Neuronal Network to predict a probability.
Unfortunately I only have Class labels, (Specific event happens or not) which are very stochastic in nature. Meaning, a seemingly very big part is random or at least not correlated in the featuredata.
It is also a time series data, but for different reasons I treat every timestamp as a different datapoint with time encoded as input label.

My labels are 0 or 1. When I downsample my dataset by using the following line:

```
input_data = block_reduce(input_data, block_size=(4, 1, 1), func=np.mean)
```

This results in some labels being of value: 0.25, 0.5 or 0.75
Up to now I only downsampled by picking every nth line and used BCELoss as my loss function.
However I realized the following:

```
>>> torch_label = torch.tensor([[1., 0.5], [1., 0.5]])
>>> torch_pred = torch.tensor([[1., 0.5], [1., 0.5]])
>>> loss_func = torch.nn.BCELoss()
>>> print(loss_func(torch_pred,torch_label))
tensor(0.3466)
```

Meaning that it does not behave the way I want it to. I tried MSELoss, but it seams wrong since I still would say i have a classification problem.

Also I actually care about the probability of the event. I currently use SGD, since adam did not work for me, since its to stachastic and a 4 layer NN. Which I optimized using grid search. I would also appreciate any tips.

Comment: I don't understand, you said your labels are binary (either `0` or `1`), but you shown the example `torch_label = torch.tensor([[1., 0.5], [1., 0.5]])` where you have `0.5` as label? You're being contradictory. If your labels are truly binary means something like `torch_label = torch.tensor([[1., 0], [1., 0]])` then `BCELoss()` would work, as it expects the label to be binary. Also I would suggest adding more code to the question and some data samples so that It is a bit clear what you're working on.

Comment: As you can see in the downsampling line (block reduce) I average over 4 lines. Meaning, if in two of those lines the value is 0 and in the other two the value is 0. the resulting new label would be 0.5.

Comment: I'm not sure why you 're downsampling but even If you do It's never the case we put our hands on `label`, the `label` is something that remains the same throughout the whole process, we don't touch it or modify it. If you could clear It out why you would choose to do so, also as I've suggested more code and data sample would help.

Comment: @KhalidSaifullah I have over 300 lines of code. I (and I might be very mistaken) am not sure that any of my code will anhance understandibility of my question. What do you think will benefit you? The first few lines of my actual data, My custom loss function, my forward pass? My problem seems to be a conceptual one, where I was hoping to find advice.

Comment: "_The first few lines of my actual data, My custom loss function, my forward pass_", yeah, these things should enhance your question and will help others to suggest you a solution.